# Need to check if Shared Preferences String or Boolean exist

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I wonder if any one can help me, i am trying to get my head around shared preferences, i assume they are stored in the device (tablet) and can be checked to see they exist.
My code below (first one) i want a button once clicked to put a string or boolean in the shared preferences.
The second code is to see if the shared prefs exist if it does make a settext change if not ignore and look for the next string

```
cala1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(View v) { 
     LoadPreferences();
         SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefman",   MODE_PRIVATE);        
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
          editor.putString("cal1","c1");
          editor.commit();                });


enter4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
             public void onClick(View v) { 
 LoadPreferences();
              SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefman", MODE_PRIVATE);        
            sharedpreferences.contains("cal1"); 

                 if (sharedpreferences.getString("cal1","c1").equals("cal1"));

                 {
                     {cexist1.setText("Shared prefs exit"); 

                 }
else
```

Comment: What is your question? You have neither stated what your question is, nor whether your provided code works or not. Help us out here...

Comment: Also, the code is incomplete, it ends on an else

Answer (score 17):

I don't get why you call `sharedpreferences.contains("cal1")` when you ignore the return value anyway. 
The Android documentation for [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) says the following:

> contains(String key) Checks whether the preferences contains a
>   preference.

Looks like that is what you want, try using the call in you if clause.

```
if (sharedpreferences.contains("cal1")) {
   cexist1.setText("Shared prefs exit"); 
}
```

the format of your code above is a bit messy too - makes it harder to read ;)

Comment: To  ask your question HXcaine my code didn't work as the second code would simply display the settext weither string was there or not. I left the code incomplete as i waanted to know if it is possible to put a few if else routines in the on click listener.

Comment: your code always set text due to the semicolon after your if clause.
thus the `cexist1.setText("Shared prefs exit");` block was always executed no matter what the if evaluated

Comment: Thanks k-mera but unfortuntly i'm still getting shared prefs exit(i mean exist mssplelling) on setext change even though i havn't hit the button on the cala1 on click listener. I need some code to see if the string has been put otherwise return a value of false.

Comment: Nice one yar... i m just looking for that.